# Uniqueness of Fano varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

It is a theorem of Kollár–Miyaoka–Mori that there is a finite number of deformation families of smooth, complex Fano $n$-folds for each $n$ (hence also a finite number of diffeomorphism types).

My question is, whether it is possible to have two diffeomorphic Fano varieties that are not in the same deformation family?